# Google custom search promise not getting completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-api, promise, webpack

I am trying to learn NodeJs and javascript with it. I tried following snippet. I used the request format from https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/promises

```
var CSE_ID = "XXX";
var API_KEY = "YYY";

const googleImages = require('google-images');
let client = googleImages(CSE_ID, API_KEY);
console.log("Execution started");
client.search('Steve Angello')
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log("Result was fetched");
      //this.results.push(response.result);
    }, function(reason) {
      console.error('Result was not fetched:',
      reason.result.error.message);
      }, this);

console.log("Execution Completed");
```

I also tried using promise as following:

```
client.search('Steve Angello')
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log("Result was fetched")
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error: " + error);
  });
```

I can see the output on console Execution Started and Execution Completed but don't see for error or that Result was fetched. I am able to see in Network calls that google Api returned the Json formatted result, something like following:

```
"searchInformation": {
  "searchTime": 0.16809,
  "formattedSearchTime": "0.17",
  "totalResults": "4580000",
  "formattedTotalResults": "4,580,000"
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "Steve Angello : Omnia",
   "htmlTitle": "\u003cb\u003eSteve Angello\u003c/b\u003e : Omnia",
   "link": "http://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/staging.omnianightclub.com/uploads/2015/05/150000_OMLV_HomepageDiamond_669x1000_SteveAngello.png",
   "displayLink": "omnianightclub.com",
   "snippet": "Steve Angello : Omnia",
   "htmlSnippet": "\u003cb\u003eSteve Angello\u003c/b\u003e : Omnia",
   "mime": "image/png",
   "fileFormat": "Image Document",
   "image": {
    "contextLink": "http://omnianightclub.com/artist/steve-angello/",
    "height": 1000,
    "width": 669,
    "byteSize": 403470,
    "thumbnailLink": "https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ56da5kw1I8l13Z8cL2reLUgS4FU1_rc6ZcW0r72GWc02gCCeMsogEwcmu",
    "thumbnailHeight": 149,
    "thumbnailWidth": 100
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "steve angello Archives | We Rave You",
   "htmlTitle": "\u003cb\u003esteve angello\u003c/b\u003e Archives | We Rave You",
   "link": "http://weraveyou.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/steve-angello.jpg",
   "displayLink": "weraveyou.com",
   "snippet": "Steve Angello compiles a firey ...",
   "htmlSnippet": "\u003cb\u003eSteve Angello\u003c/b\u003e compiles a firey ...",
   "mime": "image/jpeg",
   "image": {
    "contextLink": "http://weraveyou.com/tag/steve-angello/",
    "height": 1365,
    "width": 2048,
    "byteSize": 213185,
    "thumbnailLink": "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSwTxjcVJ87o9suz6e7K7iRW4XtJpebnTanPOGxseRypkQDOaEJezqagfs",
    "thumbnailHeight": 100,
    "thumbnailWidth": 150
   }
  }
```

PS: I am using webpack-devserver, could that be a reason ?

Comment: What is `}, this);`, on the last third line?

Comment: I used the request format from https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/features/promises

Comment: @PhatomM but you are using google-images npm package, aren't you?

Comment: Yes, I tried doing this as well
client.search('Steve Angello')
    .then(function(content) {
        console.log("Got the Content")
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
      console.error("Error: " + error);
  });